# Apama 10.3: Add pysys nature to projects

Tags: apama, pysys

I am working with Apama 10.3, in Software AG Designer.  I have a project that I'd like to add the Pysys nature to my project, but the usual attempts (right-click on project name, project > properties, etc.) don't help.  I couldn't find anything in the documentation either.

How can I work with Pysys in Designer, please?  I'd like to be able to build my tests via the IDE, for consistency and convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently eclipse/Designer doesn't have a PySys nature, but what you can do is add a generic eclipse "Python" nature – which you can do using "PyDev".

And then to launch pysys from eclipse you’ll need to add a launch configuration. There are various options but the most convenient for this purpose is the “external tool” eclipse feature.

You need to invoke pysys.py with the right environment for locating python and also Apama if you want to use it with the Apama extensions. If you’re using PySys with Apama 10.3.1+ this is easy as you can use the new capability of the apama_env.bat script to execute a command e.g. ${apama_home}\bin\apama_env pysys run –n 0 –purge. If you’re on an earlier version I’m afraid you probably need to create a trivial .bat script of your own that first runs apama_env and then pysys %*

You'll want to set the working directory in the eclipse launch config go ${project_loc}/tests so it runs all tests. Or alternatively, ${selected_resource_loc}, to invoke a specific test subtree. You could create separate launch configs for both use cases.